# How to prevent an I/O Completion Port from blocking when completion packets are available?

Tags: winsock2, iocp, overlapped-io

I have a server application that uses [Microsoft's I/O Completion Port (IOCP)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mechanism to manage asynchronous network socket communication.  In general, this IOCP approach has performed very well in my environment.  However, I have encountered an edge case scenario for which I am seeking guidance:

For the purposes of testing, my server application is streaming data (lets say ~400 KB/sec) over a gigabit LAN to a single client.  All is well...until I disconnect the client's Ethernet cable from the LAN.  Disconnecting the cable in this manner prevents the server from immediately detecting that the client has disappeared (i.e. the client's TCP network stack does not send notification of the connection's termination to the server)

Meanwhile, the server continues to make `WSASend` calls to the client...and being that these calls are asynchronous, they appear to "succeed" (i.e. the data is buffered by the OS in the outbound queue for the socket).

While this is all happening, I have 16 threads blocked on `GetQueuedCompletionStatus`, waiting to retrieve completion packets from the port as they become available.  Prior to disconnecting the client's cable, there was a constant stream of completion packets.  Now, everything (as expected) seems to have come to a halt...for about 32 seconds.  After 32 seconds, IOCP springs back into action returning `FALSE` with a non-null `lpOverlapped` value.  `GetLastError` returns 121 (The semaphore timeout period has expired.)  I can only assume that error 121 is an artifact of `WSASend` finally timing out after the TCP stack determined the client was gone?

I'm fine with the network stack taking 32 seconds to figure out my client is gone.  The problem is that while the system is making this determination, my IOCP is paralyzed.  For example, `WSAAccept` events that post to the same IOCP are not handled by any of the 16 threads blocked on `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` until the failed completion packet (indicating error 121) is received.

My initial plan to work around this involved using `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` immediately after calling `WSASend`.  If the socket event wasn't signaled within (e.g. 3 seconds), then I terminate the socket connection and move on (in hopes of preventing the extensive blocking effect on my IOCP).  Unfortunately, `WSAWaitForMultipleEvents` never seems to encounter a timeout (so maybe asynchronous sockets are signaled by virtue of being asynchronous? Or copying data to the TCP queue qualifies for a signal?)

I'm still trying to sort this all out, but was hoping someone had some insights as to how to prevent the IOCP hang.

Other details:  My server application is running on Win7 with 8 cores; IOCP is configured to use at most 8 concurrent threads;  my thread pool has 16 threads.  Plenty of RAM, processor and bandwidth.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. `WSAAccept()` is not dependent on `WSASend()` being processed first.  Especially since the two functions are being called on two separate `SOCKET` handles. If `WSAAccept()` has a pending client, it will post an IOCP event while `WSASend()` continues working in the background. This makes me think you are not managing the IOCP correctly. Please show your actual code.

Comment: I think it's a bug with your code because IOCP cannot possibly that broken. Try to create a simple repro in a few dozen lines and post it here. My guess: In the process you'll discover the bug yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.  Indeed, this question turned out to be bogus.  Unknown to me, there were really two IOCPs in the mix (one added by a colleague that utilized the same thread code).  The interaction between these two IOCPs enabled a deadlock which was producing the erroneous behavior.  Everything is working beautifully now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usual for the `WSASend()` completions to stall in this situation. You won't get them until the TCP stack times out its resend attempts and completes all of the outstanding sends in error. This doesn't block any other operations. I expect you are either testing incorrectly or have a bug in your code.

Note that your 'fix' is flawed. You could see this 'delayed send completion' situation at any point during a normal connection if the sender is sending faster than the consumer can consume. See [this article on TCP flow control and async writes](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/06/tcp-flow-control-and-asynchronous-writes.html). A better plan is to use a counter for the amount of oustanding writes (per connection) that you want to allow and stop sending if that counter gets reached and then resume when it drops below a 'low water mark' threshold value.

Note that if you've pulled out the network cable into the machine how do you expect any other operations to complete? Reads will just sit there and only fail once a write has failed and AcceptEx will simply sit there and wait for the condition to rectify itself.

Comment: Hi Len, thanks for your confirmation regarding `WSASend` stalling in this situation.

Comment: The cause of the strange behavior: a colleague had added a secondary IOCP that I was not aware of.  Together, they enabled a deadlock condition which produced my headache scenario.  I've fixed the code up and everything works stellar now.  Thanks again for your feedback and the wonderful articles you've made available on your website.

Comment: BTW: I came across your flow control article via Google before posting this question -- very well written.  My project is slated to use flow control, but I haven't implemented it yet.  Also, I apologize for not being clear on which network cable was pulled -- ClientA's cable was pulled while ClientB and the server's network remained intact.  Thanks again for your feedback.